# Edit specific columns of DetailsView using DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have employee details of each employee. When user selects edit profile, detailsview shows all his details. Now I want to be able to edit only specific columns like Mobile,Email and Address.

I have already bind data to detailsview and have onItemUpdating event to handle edited data. It is not giving me any error but its not updating data. Please tell me where Im going Wrong..

```
 protected void UserDetailsView_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        { 
                TextBox mobile = (TextBox)UserDetailsView.Rows[4].Cells[1].Controls[0];
                TextBox email = (TextBox)UserDetailsView.Rows[5].Cells[1].Controls[0];
                TextBox address = (TextBox)UserDetailsView.Rows[6].Cells[1].Controls[0]; //as TextBox;

                CurrentUser.Employee.MobileNo = mobile.Text;
                CurrentUser.Employee.Email = email.Text;
                CurrentUser.Employee.Address = address.Text;

                DataBaseManager.UpdateEmployee(CurrentUser.Employee);

                UserDetailsView.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);

                UserDetailsView.DataBind();                     
        }
```

Comment: You're calling the ````UserDetailsView.DataBind();```` but what data source are you actually binding?  There needs to be a ````UserDetailsView.DataSource = someCollection````

Comment: ````private void Bind()
        { DataTable dt = DataBaseManager.GetEmployeeDataTable();
            UserDetailsView.DataSourceID = null;
            UserDetailsView.DataSource = dt;
            UserDetailsView.DataBind();

        }

Comment: When you say "it's not updating data" can you be more specific? Do you mean it's not updating in the database, or it's not updating the HTML?

Comment: Both in database and UI. I'm using SQL Server management studio. My updateemployee method contails query for updating in database  for Mobile, email and address.

Comment: Well as far as the database update, you are not providing any code that we can help identify the issue besides ````DataBaseManager.UpdateEmployee(CurrentUser.Employee)```` and that doesn't really help at all.

Comment: You need to do some debugging.  Does CurrentEmployee have the correct data before it's sent to the UpdateEmployee function? Does the SQL query return a value or @@ROWCOUNT so you know the update works? Can you execute the SQL query by itself and it works (would indicate something is wrong with the code, not the query).

Comment: I'm using SqlDatasource as datasource in which I have select and update method.

Comment: Again, WHEN YOU DEBUG, what are you seeing? I get the impression you're not too familiar with this code that you are working on, and I think it would be helpful for you to actually debug and see what is going on.  You need to "step into" the ````DataBaseManager.UpdateEmployee(CurrentUser.Employee)```` and see WHY it isn't updating.  You might get error messages when you debug, and those are helpful to post here in your original message.

Comment: Debug documentation to help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019  -- please actually debug.  You will never learn to identify and fix problems by yourself if you do not. StackOverflow is a good resource for help fixing your solution, but it's not a place to do all the work for you.

Comment: I did debug the code. The TextBox variables mobile, email are holding the old values rather than new values. And for address it is holding "system.web.ui.webcontrol.textbox" and gets updated even in database. So I think update query is working. UPDATE query-- "UPDATE empDetails SET MobileNo= ' " +employee.MobileNo+ " ',email= ' " +employee.email+ " ',address= ' " +employee.address+ " ' where empID = ' " + employee.EmpID.ToString()+ " ' "

Comment: Okay....Do you have a ````!Page.IsPostBack()```` logic so you're only binding the grid 1 time?  It seems to be that when you're clicking a button to Update, it's rebinding the ````UserDetailsView```` and therefore you're losing the values that were entered.

Comment: Thanks alot JohnPete22 it worked. Silly mistake.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it worked out.  Another little tidbit: when I debug ASP.NET projects, I always set break-points on Page_Load to see to see if PostBacks are being triggered or not.